# How to count input state changes in Arduino or C environment?

Tags: arduino

I am working on a DIY tachometer project where I'm using an Infrared sensor module to track a black strip on a wheel attached to a motor. Whenever the sensor comes in front of the strip, a LOW output is sent to the Arduino from the sensor module, otherwise a HIGH output is sent. My question is how do I track the state changes in the input from the module every time it comes across the black strip?

For example, if it sends 1111110000011111100000 (sequences of '0' is when the sensor comes across the strip), the program should be able to detect a count of 2 (i.e., only the falling input changes should be detected by the program and the counter should be increased by 1).

I just want the shortest possible code excerpt which will do the counting effectively. I'm quite an amateur programmer, so I can't figure out how to go about it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that detect both edge of input signal using external interrupt.

Connecting output pin of sensor and INTn of arduino.

Answer (score 0):

You just need your code which you allready have and then make the light boolen true for a "1" you scanned and false for a "0". This should work. If not reply to this answer. I'll try to help you.

```
boolean lastscanned = false;
int counter = 0;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
//do your Read code here:

boolean light;// = paste your result form Reading above here.It has to
// be a boolean (true/false)
if (light = lastscanned) {
//there was no change
}else {
//there was a change
lastscanned = light; //set the lastscanned to the new one.
counter += 1;
Serial.println(counter);
}
}
```